# Chart.js - Doughnut show tooltips always?

Tags: jquery, charts

When using the Chart.js library, I can add multiple doughnuts on my page without a problem.

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart

But I cannot find a way to ***always show*** the tooltips - not only when hovering the mouse over the doughnut. Does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 43):

I had the same problem today and solved it quite easy by adding the options onAnimationComplte and tooltipevents.

onAnitmationComplete calls the method to show the tooltips like a hover event does. 
Normally you define the events in tooltipevents to display the tooltips but we need to remove them and pass an empty array.

Note:(http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart).

Javascript:

```
var options = 
{
    tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>",

    onAnimationComplete: function()
    {
        this.showTooltip(this.segments, true);

        //Show tooltips in bar chart (issue: multiple datasets doesnt work http://jsfiddle.net/5gyfykka/14/)
        //this.showTooltip(this.datasets[0].bars, true);

        //Show tooltips in line chart (issue: multiple datasets doesnt work http://jsfiddle.net/5gyfykka/14/)
        //this.showTooltip(this.datasets[0].points, true);  
    },

    tooltipEvents: [],

    showTooltips: true
}

var context = $('#chart').get(0).getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(context).Pie(data, options);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="chartContainer">
    <canvas id="chart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

Example Data:

```
var data = [
    {
        value: 300,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E"
    },
    {
        value: 50,
        color: "#46BFBD",
        highlight: "#5AD3D1"
    },
    {
        value: 100,
        color: "#FDB45C",
        highlight: "#FFC870"
    }
]
```

JSFiddle PIE:
http://jsfiddle.net/5gyfykka/

JSFiddle BAR/LINE:
http://jsfiddle.net/5gyfykka/14/

Comment: Where did you get chart object? Do you first create the chart and then you set the options?

Comment: @kentverger Yes, I changed the code so you can see how i solved it.

Comment: Just to build on that example, swap out 
"chart.showTooltip(chart.segments, true);" 
with
"this.showTooltip(this.segments, true);" 
...then you don't need to worry about naming conventions :)

Comment: @Kapi this code seems to work well only with Pie Charts, any  clue to have the same for line/bar charts ?

Comment: @manish, yes this is possible check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5gyfykka/14/. Multiple datasets dont work yet but i will try to figure this out in the near future.

Comment: @Kapi Were you able to get multiple datasets working?

Comment: How i can make this work with Doughnut?? its not working for me :(

Comment: I suggest the following solution **bar chart - multiple datasets** https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/327#issuecomment-135493617

Comment: @Kapi it works. but i overlaps on other tooltip. How to solve this? Please find solution for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34282538/chart-js-avoid-overlapping-of-tooltips-in-pie-chart question

Comment: can we use `onComplete` call back instead of `onAnimationComplete`?

Comment: Is there a way to implement the same in Angular version?
https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#doughnut-chart

Comment: The JSFiddle's are no longer working =(. It is important to use a resource link to an specific version of the Chart.js next time.

Comment: Working JSFiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/z8brxL9p/ and http://jsfiddle.net/swrqLuvj/

Comment: @adelriosantiago this approach does not work with 2.x version. I am working on AngularChart which uses 2.x version and have the similar issue.

Answer (score 13):

You can do this by writing your own plugin which supports ChartJS version > 2.1.5.

Include the following code in your script:

```
// Show tooltips always even the stats are zero

Chart.pluginService.register({
  beforeRender: function(chart) {
    if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
      // create an array of tooltips
      // we can't use the chart tooltip because there is only one tooltip per chart
      chart.pluginTooltips = [];
      chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function(sector, j) {
          chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
            _chart: chart.chart,
            _chartInstance: chart,
            _data: chart.data,
            _options: chart.options.tooltips,
            _active: [sector]
          }, chart));
        });
      });

      // turn off normal tooltips
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
    }
  },
  afterDraw: function(chart, easing) {
    if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
      // we don't want the permanent tooltips to animate, so don't do anything till the animation runs atleast once
      if (!chart.allTooltipsOnce) {
        if (easing !== 1)
          return;
        chart.allTooltipsOnce = true;
      }

      // turn on tooltips
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
      Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function(tooltip) {
        tooltip.initialize();
        tooltip.update();
        // we don't actually need this since we are not animating tooltips
        tooltip.pivot();
        tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
      });
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
    }
  }
});

// Show tooltips always even the stats are zero
```

And then just use the following line in the options of any chart on which you want to show all the tooltips available.

```
showAllTooltips: true
```

### Working Fiddle is given below

```js
// Show tooltips always even the stats are zero

Chart.pluginService.register({
  beforeRender: function(chart) {
    if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
      // create an array of tooltips
      // we can't use the chart tooltip because there is only one tooltip per chart
      chart.pluginTooltips = [];
      chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function(sector, j) {
          chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
            _chart: chart.chart,
            _chartInstance: chart,
            _data: chart.data,
            _options: chart.options.tooltips,
            _active: [sector]
          }, chart));
        });
      });

      // turn off normal tooltips
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
    }
  },
  afterDraw: function(chart, easing) {
    if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
      // we don't want the permanent tooltips to animate, so don't do anything till the animation runs atleast once
      if (!chart.allTooltipsOnce) {
        if (easing !== 1)
          return;
        chart.allTooltipsOnce = true;
      }

      // turn on tooltips
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
      Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function(tooltip) {
        tooltip.initialize();
        tooltip.update();
        // we don't actually need this since we are not animating tooltips
        tooltip.pivot();
        tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
      });
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
    }
  }
});

// Show tooltips always even the stats are zero


var canvas = $('#myCanvas2').get(0).getContext('2d');
var doughnutChart = new Chart(canvas, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: [
      "Success",
      "Failure"
    ],
    datasets: [{
      data: [45, 9],
      backgroundColor: [
        "#1ABC9C",
        "#566573"
      ],
      hoverBackgroundColor: [
        "#148F77",
        "#273746"
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    // In options, just use the following line to show all the tooltips
    showAllTooltips: true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
     <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="350" height="296"></canvas>
</div>
```

#### [**Working JSFIDDLE here.**](https://jsfiddle.net/suhaibjanjua/qz3es03j/)

Comment: You make my day ;)

Comment: How do we hide the labels when the data is hidden? I click on the dataset buttons and the pie hides but the label is still visible.

Answer (score 6):

I expanded on Kapi's method so when you hover over it you still get to keep the default functionality like color change, and when you hover over a section it will hide the rest. I think it looks better.

```
var options =
{
    onAnimationComplete: function () {
        this.showTooltip(this.segments, true);
    },        
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart").getContext("2d");
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data, options);

$("#Chart").on('mouseleave', function (){
    myPieChart.showTooltip(myPieChart.segments, true);
});
```

Comment: I try use **Chart(ctx2).Doughnut** but I get error in ***on***  function, because not defined

Comment: yes, this is not working with 2.1.3 version. we need to use 1.0.1 version

Comment: @Raghu, any suggestions for those using chart.js 2.3.x?

Comment: @Fernando http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36992922/chart-js-v2-how-to-make-tooltips-always-appear-on-pie-chart , see if the link helps.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone tries to hide some of the segment tooltips; do it in the tooltipTemplate:

```
tooltipTemplate : "<%  var percentage = Math.round(circumference / 6.283 * 100); if (percentage >8)%><%= percentage %>%";
```

for example this code checks for the %value and only displays values higher than 8% to decrease clutter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display just ONE tooltip, you have to use this code. Here is exaple for first segment.

```
chart.showTooltip([chart.segments[0]], true);
```

Function showTooltip only accepts 2 dimensional arrays for first parameter.