# Charts.js doughnut

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I'm using [Charts.js Doughnut chart](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart) that displays dynamic data which arrives on time intervals.
When I cancel the time intervals calls or reload the page! it looks fine:

[image]

When I refresh that with time intervals and go over with mouse it seems that it draw another layer on each call.

[image]

I already tried to draw it once and to remove and set the new data, but it still goes crazy on mouse over.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('modular-doughnut');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , canvas.width, canvas.height );
var moduleDoughnut = new Chart(context).Doughnut(chart_data, config);
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @Koogle I can say that the problem is in tooltips.

**How to solve that?**

Comment: Because chart.js uses the html-canvas I think you have to clear the canvas before you redraw.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: Can you setup some jsfiddle with sample data?

Comment: I already use context.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , canvas.width, canvas.height );

Comment: To you do that once when you setup the chart or on mouse over to?

Comment: I have calls to service every 20 sec, it happens after the second call (the code above repeated)

Comment: Is the problem related to the display of the tooltip? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661197/chart-js-doughnut-show-tooltips-always)

Comment: Yes, it happens on mouse over for tooltips, but I do whant to see the tooltips

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the same canvas you have to clear the reference(s) to it. Charts.js states that you must use .destroy() to clear all references to the canvas.

You read about it here: [Charts.js .destroy()](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/?q=destr)

I had the same issue in some dynamic charts that I made so I found it easier to just create a div around the canvas, clear the div using jquery $("#divID").empty(), and then append the new canvas.