# Show the tooltip of a specific point in a line chart after the initial animation is complete

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Assume that we have the following line chart in Chart.js 2:

https://jsfiddle.net/742zut83/

The code is as follows:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Immediately after the initial animation, I would like the tooltip for a specific point, e.g. the point labeled "Green", to appear, as if one had hovered over the point, and stay there until the end of time. The default behavior of a tooltip appearing, when one hovers over a point, should preferably be disabled for all points, leaving the chart somewhat static after the initial animation is complete and the tooltip of interest has appeared.