# How to create a donut chart like this in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[image]

I am not able to put text like 15% or 16% in the graph. I s there any way to do it.

Comment: Downvoters please tell the reason to downvote.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966817/how-to-add-text-inside-the-doughnut-chart-using-chart-js

Comment: @Invictus I downvoted you because you put no effort in creating this question. You might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ok @Nick  . I am making a plunker of this to show my effort. I and yes I have read the question.
I want to insert the value as shown in my image i.e. In bitween the circular stript where the color is filled. 
I don't mean to insert in inside the blank circular hole of donut.

Answer (score 3):

Since the chart generation has changed a lot from Chart 1.X ([docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs)) to 2.X ([docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs)), it all depend on the version you are currently using for your project :

## Version 1.X

**Not available for Doughnut charts**

If you are working with Pie charts, it is built in in the data you are passing to the chart.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehak1ajz/) for more information and a full result.

---

## Version 2.X

**Two methods :**

- You can [create a new chart type](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-writing-new-scale-types) using `.extend()` method.

  Then during the creation of the new type, you *draw* the percentage in the section.
  Check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6fajwg8/) to see the result (*better than the first version, IMHO*).
- You can force the tooltip to always be enabled (as asked in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241610/how-to-show-tooltips-always-on-chart-js-2)).

  You will just have to edit what is displayed in the tooltip to put the percentage instead of the value. And also move (edit `X` and `Y` positions) the tooltip to appear where it should be.

  *The image displays a Pie chart, but you can make it work for a Doughnut.*

  [image]

Comment: Thanks from this I was able to understand how to extent the doughnut to show values instead of the percentage. In case anyone is trying to figure that out I just modified slightly the V2 jsFindle verson http://jsfiddle.net/g6fajwg8/1/