# Chartjs labels and legend

Tags: label, legend, chart.js

I have an application which contains some ChartJS.
Charts work well and legend is shown when mouse is hover the chart.
How can I configure charts to have legend and labels value all the time on chart, not only when hover.

Comment: Go to this answer and make sure to check the comments too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31319834/5289359

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show tooltips always on Chart.js 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241610/how-to-show-tooltips-always-on-chart-js-2)