# How to display data values on Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is it possible using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) to display data values?

I want to print the graph.

Thanks for any advice..

Comment: my graph is working perfectly ..i just want to display data values in my LineBar chart.. then i can print my graphs.. because now i can display data values just by mouse event

Answer (score 181, accepted):

There is an official plugin for Chart.js 2.7.0+ to do this: *[Datalabels](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels)*

Otherwise, you can loop through the points / bars onAnimationComplete and display the values

---

**Preview**

[image]

---

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myChart1" height="300" width="500"></canvas>
<canvas id="myChart2" height="300" width="500"></canvas>
```

**Script**

```
var chartData = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
    datasets: [
        {
            fillColor: "#79D1CF",
            strokeColor: "#79D1CF",
            data: [60, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }
    ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart1").getContext("2d");
var myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(chartData, {
    showTooltips: false,
    onAnimationComplete: function () {

        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.font = this.scale.font;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.scale.textColor
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";

        this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            dataset.points.forEach(function (points) {
                ctx.fillText(points.value, points.x, points.y - 10);
            });
        })
    }
});

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart2").getContext("2d");
var myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(chartData, {
    showTooltips: false,
    onAnimationComplete: function () {

        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.font = this.scale.font;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.scale.textColor
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";

        this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            dataset.bars.forEach(function (bar) {
                ctx.fillText(bar.value, bar.x, bar.y - 5);
            });
        })
    }
});
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uh9vw0ao/

Comment: What if i had two line chart in the same Chart ?

Comment: With the above it would still show the values, but you might see an overlap if the points are too close to each other. But you can always put in logic to change the value position. Like for instance - http://jsfiddle.net/hh719qex/ if you have a color printer. If you have only 2 series you could also do stuff like setting the textBaseline different IF the 2 points are 2 close to each other.

Comment: Can you add styles to this data above the points? Maybe use the styles from the generic chartjs tooltips?

Comment: @TomRudge - sure, just change the part where you set the ctx properties to use whichever font/color you wish. Cheers!

Comment: @potatopeelings Thanks, can we add a bubble to the data like on the tooltips styling? or are we limited to just font color and type?

Comment: @TomRudge - sure you could use `Chart.helpers.drawRoundedRectangle`, but I think it would be simpler then to just show the tooltips themselves (for all elements). I think there is already an answer that does this (search for tooltips.. with [chart.js]).

Comment: @potatopeelings is it possible to have showTooltips: true ? Current if i set it to true it removes the labels after I hover over a bar.

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi - yep, but then you need to move your tooltip code to an extension. See http://jsfiddle.net/4d5ojt0t/

Comment: this was for the v1.0.2 how to do this for v2.1.3?The object structure is different in the later version.

Comment: @potatopeelings I have used the `onComplete` callback here but it also fires when the mouseover is on the bar's of the chart causing the number to blink due to redraw.Would that be same if `onAnimationComplete`? I am unable to use this callback with my existing chart code (see `var chartBar` at the bottom http://pastebin.com/tT7yTkGh)

Comment: It is throwing error saying `Cannot read property 'ctx' of undefined`

Comment: @potatopeelings What if I have too may values for example 360 different values when I show the graph is looks like a line instead of curve. Also I need to have a lot of values in X.

Comment: Giving error as
(1)Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
(2)Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).Bar is not a function

Comment: I need both tool tip and data on top of the bar in my graph. When tool tip is showing, the data on top of the bar is turned to white colour which is visible in my transparent tool tip. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 94):

This works for Chart.js 2.3, including for both line/bar types.

**Important:** Even if you don't need the animation, don't change the duration option to 0. Otherwise, you will get *chartInstance.controller is undefined* error.

```js
var chartData = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
        datasets: [
            {
                fillColor: "#79D1CF",
                strokeColor: "#79D1CF",
                data: [60, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
            }
        ]
    };

var opt = {
    events: false,
    tooltips: {
        enabled: false
    },
    hover: {
        animationDuration: 0
    },
    animation: {
        duration: 1,
        onComplete: function () {
            var chartInstance = this.chart,
                ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
            ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

            this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                    var data = dataset.data[index];
                    ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
                });
            });
        }
    }
};
var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart1"),
    myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
       type: 'bar',
       data: chartData,
       options: opt
    });
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart1" height="300" width="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" when trying this on bar graphs.  Do bars use something other than "dataset.metaData[i]._model"?

Comment: It's actually var model = dataset._meta[i].data[0]._model;

Comment: That's also not the full truth. I still get exceptions.
Will try to figure it out.

Comment: var model = dataset._meta[0].data[i]._model; actually.

Comment: Looks like it is not as simple as _meta[0]. In fact the _meta object isn't an array, it has a single element with a number as the key. I can't figure out the rationale behind what the number will be so I just take the first element by looking in the keys list, like this :

var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;

Comment: If your labels are getting cut off by the scale boundaries:
See @Hung Tran solution below, or calculate and set y-axis Max property, so chartjs doesn't need to auto calculate chart area, like so:
  
     yAxes: [{
        gridLines: { display: false },
        ticks: {
            // add extra padding (5%) on y-axis by calculating max data point + 5%
            // this way chartjs doesn't need to auto calculate chart area and  so the labels are not cut off 
            max: Math.max.apply(null, [Your Data Array]) * 1.05 
        }
    }]

Comment: I am using pie chart and would like to show lable in the center or outside of bar chart. Can you please also share the code for pie chart as well? Also the signature of fillText does not have parameters. I am using 2.7.0 version.

Comment: I noticed that all the labels are centered and overlapped on each other.

Comment: This answer needs updated. The code example given is broken.

Answer (score 54):

If you are using the plugin [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com) then the following code options object will help.

Make sure you import `import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';` in your TypeScript file or add reference to `<script src="chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js"></script>` in your javascript file and register the plugin using ChartJS.register(ChartDataLabels).

```
options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins: {
        datalabels: {
            anchor: 'end',
            align: 'top',
            formatter: Math.round,
            font: {
                weight: 'bold'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is so simple and worked for me. Thank you.
Happy coding.

Comment: Really nice solution! Thank you kind stranger :-*

Comment: This is the best!

Comment: This plugin no longer registers itself automatically. It must be manually registered  `Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);`

Comment: This is the best and simpler answer here, no mumbo-jumbo needed to get it working.

Answer (score 36):

This animation option works for 2.1.3 on a bar chart.

Slightly modified [Ross answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631354/how-to-display-data-values-on-chart-js/37550150#37550150):

```
animation: {
    duration: 0,
    onComplete: function () {
        // render the value of the chart above the bar
        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
        ctx.fillStyle = this.chart.config.options.defaultFontColor;
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
        this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
                ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, model.y - 5);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I also had to set `hover: {animationDuration: 0}` to stop the labels animating away on hover

Comment: Also, note that if you want to hide labels when you hide something from the legend, you need to add the following before the forEach loop: `.filter(dataset => !dataset._meta[0].hidden)`

Comment: This method causes the values to clip if there's not enough room above the bars.

Comment: Can't believe it's that ugly ^^ nice job

Comment: Looks good, but blinks when tooltips are re-drawn. Also does not process collisions on combined charts and cumulative data labels for stacked bars – that will of course require more coding.

Comment: I did this and its working but all the labels are centered to the pie chart and it is not displayed similar to tooltip. In tooltip we see "lable: value" but with this approach we only see values.

Answer (score 26):

Based on [Ross's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631354/how-to-display-data-values-on-chart-js/37550150#37550150) for Chart.js 2.0 and up, I had to include a little tweak to guard against the case when the bar's heights comes too chose to the scale boundary.

[image: Example]

The `animation` attribute of the bar chart's option:

```
animation: {
            duration: 500,
            easing: "easeOutQuart",
            onComplete: function () {
                var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
                ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                        var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model,
                            scale_max = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._yScale.maxHeight;
                        ctx.fillStyle = '#444';
                        var y_pos = model.y - 5;
                        // Make sure data value does not get overflown and hidden
                        // when the bar's value is too close to max value of scale
                        // Note: The y value is reverse, it counts from top down
                        if ((scale_max - model.y) / scale_max >= 0.93)
                            y_pos = model.y + 20;
                        ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, y_pos);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: The text blinks on mouseover of the chart.. I tried calling `ctx.save()` at the end but it did not help

Comment: the `onComplete` call back is executed when I hovered on the bar's which causes the redraw & text appears to blink.Would this be the same with `onAnimationComplete` as well?I am unable to use the `onAnimationComplete` call back with my existing code (see `var chartBar` at the bottom of http://pastebin.com/tT7yTkGh

Comment: Is it possible to do the same in pie chart

Comment: @RaviKhambhati Yes, you can check it out in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38797604/6402571

Answer (score 22):

I think the nicest option to do this in Chart.js v2.x is by using a plugin, so you don't have a large block of code in the options. In addition, it prevents the data from disappearing when hovering over a bar.

I.e., simply use this code, which registers a plugin that adds the text after the chart is drawn.

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    afterDraw: function(chartInstance) {
        var ctx = chartInstance.chart.ctx;

        // render the value of the chart above the bar
        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

        chartInstance.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
                ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, model.y - 2);
            }
        });
  }
});
```

Comment: Chart.plugins.register({

Comment: I had to use `Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.enabled = false;`. The issue with that solution is that the `afterDraw` function is called hundreds of times, probably generating CPU overhead. Still, it's the only answer for now without blinks. If you need a better rendering for `horizontalBar` charts, use `ctx.textAlign = 'left'; ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';` and `ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x+5, model.y);`.

Comment: a far more cleaner and modular solution.

Answer (score 9):

Following this [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661197/chart-js-doughnut-show-tooltips-always/25913101#25913101), I'd use these options for a bar chart:

```
var chartOptions = {
    animation: false,
    responsive : true,
    tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>",
    tooltipFillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    tooltipFontColor: "#444",
    tooltipEvents: [],
    tooltipCaretSize: 0,
    onAnimationComplete: function()
    {
        this.showTooltip(this.datasets[0].bars, true);
    }
};

window.myBar = new Chart(ctx1).Bar(chartData, chartOptions);
```

[image: Bar Chart]

This still uses the tooltip system and his advantages (automatic positionning, templating, ...) but hiding the decorations (background color, caret, ...)

Comment: Implementation may change depending on chart type. For a line chart, for example, it's `this.datasets[0].points` instead of `.bars`. I do prefer this solution because it uses the tooltip system.

Comment: This solution for an earlier version.How to achieve this for the latest version i.e  2.1.3. I have used the potatopeelings & Huang Trang answers in the animations `onComplete` callback but it is triggered even when hovered over the bars of the chart which causes the text to redraw & give an unwanted blink effect.I also tried `afterDraw` & it is all same.Strangely it doesnt happen in fiddle provided by potatopeelings.Any Ideas plz?

Answer (score 9):

I'd recommend using this plugin: *[datalabels](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels)*

Labels can be added to your charts simply by importing the plugin into the JavaScript file, for example:

```
import 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels'
```

And can be fine-tuned using this documentation: *https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/options.html*

Comment: Easiest one, does not require "code", just customization using the standard "options" object. A heads-up: minimum required charts.js version is **2.7.0**, I was referencing 2.5.0 from CDN and there were no changes on the charts...

Comment: @GBU what is the option attribute ?.

Comment: Also note this is an Official chartjs plugin, not a 3rd party helper

Comment: The second link is broken (404).

Answer (score 9):

Adapted the @Ross answer to work with 3.7.0 version of the Chartjs

```
animation: {
        duration: 0,
        onComplete: function() {
            ctx = this.ctx;
            ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.font.size, Chart.defaults.font.style, Chart.defaults.font.family);
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
            chartinst = this;
            this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
                if(chartinst.isDatasetVisible(i)){
                    var meta = chartinst.getDatasetMeta(i);
                    meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
                        var data = dataset.data[index];
                        ctx.fillText(data, bar.x, bar.y - 5);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

In this case, animation can be 0
To have a nicer looking, you can disable the hover and the tooltip if you want a more "static" visualization

Also, the isDataSetVisible works to get rid of the numbers that stay shown when you hide the dataset in case of multiple datasets

Comment: Thanks for this. It works even on 3.9.1.

Comment: I tried ALL answers before that aimed at version 2. This is the one that works with Chart.js 3+. Thanks a lot. – Only on mouse over the labels disappear and the mouse tooltip appears instead.

Comment: One question remains: How to label the sectors of a *pie chart*. The answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71655568/1066234

Comment: This is what worked for me out of everything here (v3.3.2)

Comment: it worked for version 4.3.0

Answer (score 7):

From Chart.js samples (file *Chart.js-2.4.0/samples/data_labelling.html*):

```
        // Define a plugin to provide data labels

        Chart.plugins.register({
            afterDatasetsDraw: function(chartInstance, easing) {
                // To only draw at the end of animation, check for easing === 1
                var ctx = chartInstance.chart.ctx;

                chartInstance.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                    var meta = chartInstance.getDatasetMeta(i);
                    if (!meta.hidden) {
                        meta.data.forEach(function(element, index) {
                            // Draw the text in black, with the specified font
                            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';

                            var fontSize = 16;
                            var fontStyle = 'normal';
                            var fontFamily = 'Helvetica Neue';
                            ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(fontSize, fontStyle, fontFamily);

                            // Just naively convert to string for now
                            var dataString = dataset.data[index].toString();

                            // Make sure alignment settings are correct
                            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                            ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';

                            var padding = 5;
                            var position = element.tooltipPosition();
                            ctx.fillText(dataString, position.x, position.y - (fontSize / 2) - padding);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: I added a line to this for alignment on a Horizontal Bar Chart by doing if(chart.config.type == "horizontalBar") then defining a custom vertical padding of 10 to center align it.

Comment: Even with the reference and code comments, an explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What are the properties of this solution? In what way does it solve the problem in the question? Pros/cons? Etc. From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42391757/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: OK, the OP seems to have left the building, so this is unlikely to ever happen. Perhaps somebody else can chime in and reverse engineer this and provide the information?

Answer (score 7):

From my experience, once you include the [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/releases/) plugin (make sure to place the `<script>` tag after the chart.js tag on your page), your charts begin to display values.

If you then choose you can customize it to fit your needs. [The customization is clearly documented here](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/options.html) but basically, the format is like this hypothetical example:

```
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: yourDataObject,
    options: {
        // other options
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                anchor :'end',
                align :'top',
                // and if you need to format how the value is displayed...
                formatter: function(value, context) {
                    return GetValueFormatted(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I edited [Aaron Hudon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631354/how-to-display-data-values-on-chart-js/38514516#38514516) a little, but **only for bar charts**. My version adds:

- Fade in animation for the values.
- Prevent clipping by positioning the value inside the bar if the bar is too high.
- No blinking.

[image: Example]

Downside: When hovering over a bar that has a value inside it, the value might look a little jagged. I have not found a solution do disable hover effects. It might also need tweaking depending on your own settings.

Configuration:

```
bar: {
  tooltips: {
    enabled: false
  },
  hover: {
    animationDuration: 0
  },
  animation: {
    onComplete: function() {
      this.chart.controller.draw();
      drawValue(this, 1);
    },
    onProgress: function(state) {
      var animation = state.animationObject;
      drawValue(this, animation.currentStep / animation.numSteps);
    }
  }
}
```

Helpers:

```
// Font color for values inside the bar
var insideFontColor = '255,255,255';
// Font color for values above the bar
var outsideFontColor = '0,0,0';
// How close to the top edge bar can be before the value is put inside it
var topThreshold = 20;

var modifyCtx = function(ctx) {
  ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
  return ctx;
};

var fadeIn = function(ctx, obj, x, y, black, step) {
  var ctx = modifyCtx(ctx);
  var alpha = 0;
  ctx.fillStyle = black ? 'rgba(' + outsideFontColor + ',' + step + ')' : 'rgba(' + insideFontColor + ',' + step + ')';
  ctx.fillText(obj, x, y);
};

var drawValue = function(context, step) {
  var ctx = context.chart.ctx;

  context.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
      var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
      var textY = (model.y > topThreshold) ? model.y - 3 : model.y + 20;
      fadeIn(ctx, dataset.data[i], model.x, textY, model.y > topThreshold, step);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Janne, thank you for the solution, it looks great. But I have a situation where my values are actually kinda big (5 decimal numbers), and when the screen size is small or I have many charts, the numbers are on top of each other. Is there any way to make this work with responsivity? Like, make the numbers rotate when there is no space, just like the labels below the bar?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I think it should be possible to rotate by checking current screen size in the modifyCtx function and using ctx.rotate. However I'm not sure how to compare the value size to the available space to determine when to rotate.

Comment: The modifyCtx function only works once, and not on resize, right? I'll take a look at the chart.js source code and see where they do the rotation of the labels in the x axis. If I see something I'll try to do something and tell you in here, ok? =)

Comment: I have found something on the version 2.3.0, line 7075. [`calculateTickRotation`](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/core/core.scale.js#L182), it's inside the Scale function. I'll analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent your numbers from being cut off if they're too close to the top of the canvas:

```
yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
        stepSize: Math.round((1.05*(Math.max.apply(Math, myListOfyValues)) / 10)/5)*5,
        suggestedMax: 1.05*(Math.max.apply(Math, myListOfyValues)),
        beginAtZero: true,
        precision: 0
    }
}]
```

- 10 = the number of ticks
- 5 = rounds tick values to the nearest 5 - all y values will be incremented evenly
- 1.05 = increases the maximum y axis tick value so the numbers don't get cut off

Something similar will work for *xAxes* too.