# How to add index labels(on top of bar charts) in Chart.js

Tags: angularjs, charts, chart.js, angular-chart

I am using angular-chart.js(which uses Chart.js) to create charts in my angular app. I want to add values on top of the bars in a bar chart. 
If extending the defaults charts in Chart.js is the only way, can you please provide a reference code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the answer here [how to display data values on Chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631354/how-to-display-data-values-on-chart-js/31632707#31632707) and modify the callback function slightly to show the index values instead of the values

```
...
this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
    dataset.bars.forEach(function (bar, i) {
        ctx.fillText(i + 1, bar.x, bar.y - 5);
    });
})
...
```

The callback can be passed in via the angular-chart options parameter. You won't be extending the chart type, so you won't need to register a new directive with angular-chart.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zkqu7tsp/

Comment: Could you please extend the answer as to show how to pass the callback through the angular-chart options parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This is the onAnimationComplete callback for angular-chart options

```
onAnimationComplete: function () {
        var chart = this.chart;
        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
                                                                     this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
         dataset.bars.forEach(function (bar, i) {
         console.log(bar)
             ctx.fillText(bar.value, bar.x, bar.y - 5);
         });
     })
```

Hope this helps you ..