# Prevent size of canvas chart js to equal window height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I am [using chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-introduction) to display data and the chart (canvas) takes up 100% width and 100% height of the window.

I want to reduce this to be `600px` by `600px`. To do this I tried using 
`Chart.defaults.global.legend.fullWidth = false;` however this didn't work.

I have created a [jsfiddle her](https://jsfiddle.net/ce7rgaz6/)e for your convenience.

See code below:

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = "#000";
Chart.defaults.global.legend.fullWidth = false;
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Followers',
            data: followers,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.9)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.9)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.9)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.9)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.9)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.9)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 5
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 'responsive: false' to the chart options

```
options: {
        responsive: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
```

Comment: nice! did you see that in the docs, or have you used this library before?

Comment: but it is mentioned in the docs too
[link](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-creating-a-chart-with-options)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994101/chartjs-show-value-on-pie-chart I have asked another question here if you want to take a look when you get a chance

Comment: I checked your other question and if I understand everything correctily it is possible a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33363373/how-to-display-pie-chart-data-values-of-each-slice-in-chart-js)

Comment: it is aniko, thanks! i am trying to implement the solution now. Also, can you see that the label #number of followers isn't showing. You have any idea why?

Comment: should this label be the title of the whole chart?

Comment: you see in the datasets where it says `label: '# of Followers'`? I thought this should show the title of the chart. It works for a bar chart but not for a pie chart

Comment: no, it is a title of a dataset and it cannot be used with pichart. So if you want to add a title to your chart, enable title in the options part of the config

`options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Custom Chart Title'
        }
    }`