# Is it a bug? Value of pie chart showed twice react-chart.js and Chart.PieceLabel.js

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs

I made a pie chart using react-chart.js and Chart.PieceLabel.js. I could show the value of slice of pie chart. I could show the value with % thanks to this question [Displaying pie chart data value of each slices using react-chartjs-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447098/displaying-pie-chart-data-value-of-each-slices-using-react-chartjs-2/46447313#46447313)

However, strangely two value (one with white and the other with black) showed up.

How can I remove the one of value? I want to remove the black one.

Here is the image.

[image]

```
export default class Categories extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        slideOpen : false,
        piData : piData
      }

this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
this.update = this.update.bind(this);
this.doParentToggle = this.doParentToggle.bind(this);
}

doParentToggle(){


this.setState({
    piData : piData
  })
  this.update();
  }

handleClick(){
    this.setState({
        slideOpen : !this.state.slideOpen
    })
}

update() {
  var piData;
  this.setState({
    piData : piData
  })
 }    

  componentDidMount() {
    let ctx = this.refs.chart.chart_instance.chart.ctx;
    console.log(this.refs.chart.chart_instance.chart.ctx); // returns a Chart.js instance reference
    this.refs.chart.chart_instance.chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                if(dataset.type === 'bar'){
                    const dataArray = dataset.data;
                    dataset._meta[0].data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                        ctx.fillText(dataArray[index], bar._view.x, bar._view.y);
                    });
                };
            })
  }

render(){


 const CategoriesPanel = this.state.slideOpen? "slideOpen" : "";
 const { length } = this.props


  var totalData = piData + piData2 + piData3 + piData4 + piData5;

   let newpiData =  function() {
   return parseFloat((piData /  totalData ) * 100 ).toFixed(2) };

   let newpiData2 =  function() {
   return parseFloat((piData2 /  totalData ) * 100).toFixed(2) };

   let newpiData3 =  function() {
   return  parseFloat((piData3 /  totalData ) * 100).toFixed(2) };

   let newpiData4 =  function() {
   return parseFloat((piData4 /  totalData ) * 100).toFixed(2) };

   let newpiData5 =  function() {
   return parseFloat((piData5 /  totalData ) * 100).toFixed(2) };


  const data = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [ newpiData() , newpiData2(), newpiData3(), newpiData4(), newpiData5()],
    backgroundColor: [
    'orange',
    'blue',
    'red',
    'purple',
    'green'
    ],
    borderColor: [ 
    'orange',
    'blue',
    'red',
    'purple',
    'green'
    ]
  }]};

  var pieOptions = {
      pieceLabel: {
     render: function (args) {
              return args.value + '%';
            },
     fontSize: 30,
     fontColor: '#fff'
   }
  };

  const bardata = {
  labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
  datasets: [
   {
  backgroundColor: [
    'orange',
    'blue',
    'red',
    'purple',
    'green'
    ],
  borderColor: 'black',
  borderWidth: 1,
  hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
  hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
  data: [ newpiData(), newpiData2() , newpiData3()  , newpiData4()  , newpiData5()  ]
  }
  ]
  };

  let options = {
    plugins: {
    datalabels: {
    display: true,
    color: 'white',
   },
   font: {
          weight: 'bold'
        }
  }
  }

  return(
<div>
<div id="chart" className={CategoriesPanel}>
<div style={{"display" : "flex"}}>
<Pie style={{"fontSize" : "20px" }} data={data} options={pieOptions}/>
<HorizontalBar
      ref='chart'
      data={bardata}
      width={100}
      height={50}
       options={{
        maintainAspectRatio: false

      }}
    />
</div>
 </div>
<div className="categoriesSlide" onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.slideOpen? <img src={Arrowup} alt="arrowup" className="arrowup" /> : <img src={Arrowdown} alt="arrowdown" className="arrowdown"/>}</div>
 <div className="clear">
 <List parentToggle={this.doParentToggle} />
 <ListSecond parentToggle={this.doParentToggle} />
 <ListThird parentToggle={this.doParentToggle} />
 <ListFourth parentToggle={this.doParentToggle} />
 <ListFifth parentToggle={this.doParentToggle} />

 </div>
 </div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: Hm.. not exactly sure what's causing this.. Though you should remove the `componentDidMount` method *(the code inside)*, that looks irrelevant. Consider creating a working demo [**here**](https://stackblitz.com/), so it'll be easier to figure out the issue.

Comment: I created a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c3fmyz). This time, value from Chart.PieceLabel.js does not show up.

Comment: It does. You have to expand the view window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is causing because of the **`chartjs-plugin-datalabels`** plugin.

By default it shows data labels on all available charts, and to make it not show the labels on a particular chart, you need to set the **`display`** property to **`false`**. So, in your case set the following option inside `pieOptions` :

```
plugins: {
   datalabels: {
      display: false
   }
}
```

Here is the [**working example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3jufpp)