# How to display data value on selected graph only, in a mixed chart? (ChartJS)

Tags: chart.js

I have a mixed chart of bar and line graphs. Both are showing their data labels but I only want the bar graph to show its own data labels and not the line graph.

I've got this code from [How to show data values or index labels in ChartJs (Latest Version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344582/how-to-show-data-values-or-index-labels-in-chartjs-latest-version)

How should I tweak it?

```
animation: {
       onComplete: function() {
           var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
           ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
           ctx.fillStyle = "white";
           ctx.textAlign = "center";
           ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";

           this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) 
           {
                for( var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++ )
                {
                     for(var key in dataset._meta)
                     {
                         var model = dataset._meta[key].data[i]._model;
                         ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, model.y+15);
                     }
                 }
            });
       }
}
```

Comment: You may want to look into using the plug-in for labels instead of manually worrying about that. They have a ton of configurability. https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com

Comment: I've looked into it and it was a lot easier to implement. Thanks a lot sir!