# how can i show labels and value in both on bar chart

Tags: chart.js, angular7

hello everyone i am creation a dashboard that contains bar chart using Angular 7 ,[chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/)  and [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/samples/index.html)
as you can see in the  [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKsqS.png)   the bar chart contains different data sets each one has it's own label i wanted to show the label on each one on top of the bar and its value but i did not know how my code only shows me the label of data-set
what i mean is as you can see in my code (.ts) file

```
this.chartdef= new Chart('defaut',
          {
            type:'bar',

            options:{
              cutoutPercentage:40,
              responsive :true,

              title:{
                display:true,
                text:'TRG VAGUE'
              },
              plugins:{
                datalabels:{
                  align:'top',
                  display: 'true',
                  color:'#ffffff',

                }
              }


            },
            data:{
              labels:['poste1','poste2','poste3'],
              datasets:[
                {
                  label:'REPERTOP01',
                  data:[10,7.5,4.5],
                  backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 0, 0,1)',
                  borderColor:'rgba(255, 0, 0,0.6)',
                  borderWidth:1,
                  fill:false,
                  datalabels: {
                    align: 'end',
                    anchor: 'end',


                    formatter: function(value, context) {
                      return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
                    }

                  }

                },
                {
                  label:'REPERTOP02',
                  data:[4.5,0,1],
                  backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 102, 0,1)',
                  borderColor:'rgba(255, 102, 0,0.6)',
                  fill:false,
                  borderWidth:1
                },
                {
                  label:'REPERTOP02',
                  data:[4.5,0,0],
                  backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 225, 0,1)',
                  borderColor:'rgba(255, 225, 0,0.6)',
                  fill:false,
                  borderWidth:1
                }
              ]

            }
          })
```

and html file

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <canvas id="defaut" height="40px"  width="100%">

  </canvas>
</div>
```

i have 3 data-sets i want to show on top of each bar its label i like `REPERTOP01` but this code shows me `poste1`on top of the bar and also if i show the label the value disappear so how can i show `REPERTOP01` instead of `poste1` `poste2`and `poste3` and show the value with it inside the bar

Answer (score 0):

For the text label issue, you'll need to change your custom formatter to return the dataset label instead:

```js
formatter: function(value, context) {
  return context.chart.data.datasets[context.dataIndex].label;
}
```

The datalabels plugin does not support multiple labels per bar to the best of my knowledge. You'll need to manually draw one of the labels yourself following something like this SO answer: [How to show data values or index labels in ChartJs (Latest Version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344582/how-to-show-data-values-or-index-labels-in-chartjs-latest-version).