# chartjs 2.7 how to add labels in center of horizontal bar graph

Tags: chart.js

I have a graph that look like the following with tooltips enables as these are required.

[image: My current version]

I am wanting to put labels on the 0 for the middle value between the min and max values.

The result I'm looking for is.

[image]

I've look through the documentation but cannot find anything that seems relevant.

Thanks in advance.

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/wbLgmaur/23/)

```
    horizonalBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
            datasets: [
                {
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,250,0)",
                    data: ["3.77", "4.89", "3.91", "3.34", "3.82", "3.85", "3.94", "3.83", "3.73", "3.33", "2.6", "3.86", "2.95", "3.12", "3.18", "3.05", "2.9"],
                    label: null
                },
                {
                    backgroundColor: ["#003f5c", "#003f5c", "#2f4b7c", "#2f4b7c", "#665191", "#665191", "#665191", "#665191", "#665191", "#a05195", "#a05195", "#d45087", "#d45087", "#d45087", "#d45087", "#d45087", "#d45087", "#f95d6a", "#f95d6a"],
                    data: ["1.78", "1.84", "1.61", "1.58", "1.6", "1.6", "1.6", "1.67", "1.73", "1.64", "1.86", "1.69", "1.77", "1.76", "1.74", "1.77", "1.79"],
                    label: null
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: ''
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        steps: 8,
                        stepSize: 1,
                        max: 8,
                        min: 0,
                        callback: function (value, index, values) {
                            return value - 4;
                        }
                    },
                    stacked: true
                }],
                yAxes: [
                    {
                        barPercentage: 0.6,
                        display: true,
                        position: 'left',
                        type: 'category',
                        labels: ["-9.72", "-7.16", "11.51", "13.39", "-4.41", "-3.31", "-9", "-41.33", "-16.88", "-3.63", "17.2", "-20.62", "-6.9", "-5.4", "-7.6", "-5.44", "-3.58"],
                        weight: 1,
                        stacked: true
                    },
                    {
                        offset: true,
                        display: true,
                        position: 'right',
                        type: 'category',
                        labels: ["10.92", "8.76", "-11.91", "-4.99", "64.41", "101.91", "149.4", "169.73", "45.08", "7.23", "-22", "109.62", "12.7", "6.2", "8.4", "6.84", "4.18"],
                        gridLines: {
                            display: false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can put the label under the bar.

What you can do, is to place the label inside the bar as explained in the documentation, using the property "mirror"

[Displaying the labels inside the chart instead of outside](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#common-configuration)

You can find a good example of this configuration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40477533/8941051)