# Chart.js v2 Show Data Points Above Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

Is there a way to customize the snippets [available here](https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) to make the bar chart have data points above? I know angular-chart.js uses Chart.js V2 and the questions I found were already old. Like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631354/how-to-display-data-values-on-chart-js) but it's not being wrapped in Angular.

JavaScript from the Demo:

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("BarCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
  $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];

  $scope.data = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  ];
});
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar"
  chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series">
</canvas>
```