# Chartjs radar indexed labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, chart.js, radar-chart

I am using chartjs to draw a radar chart.

The value is shown on hover in the point of the chart, but I would like to show the value always. I need to change the view to show the data when I print the page.

This is my current chart. The label is shown on hover

[image: This is my current chart. The label is shown on hover]

I want to show the value always, like in the following image
[image: I want to show the value always, like in the following image]

Answer (score 3):

***The following answer only works for Chart.js v2.***
If you want a v1 solution, check [pritishvaidya's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40239879/4864023).

---

You want to use the `animation` property of the chart options :

```js
options : {
    animation: {
        duration: 500,
        onComplete: function () {
            // The code here will be executed at the end of the animation 
            // (after 500ms here)

            // You can get the canvas context using the following :
            var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
            // `this` being the chart instance
        }
    }
}
```

---

Now you want to add the value of the point above it, which can be done using the data model, which you can find in the dataset properties :

```js
onComplete: function() {
    // You get the canvas context, to help you writing what you want
    var ctx = this.chart.ctx;

    // Here you set the context with what you need (font, size, color ...)
    ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';

    // For every dataset ...
    this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {

        // For every data in the dataset ...
        for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {

            // We get its model
            var model = dataset._meta[0].data[i]._model;

            // And write the data above it
            ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, model.y - 2);
            // You can edit the last two arguments according to what you need
        }
    });
}
```

---

Follows the result of the above code, which you can find [on this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f794khyf/) :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On the chart js [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/),you can run the functions when the animation completes using `onAnimationComplete : function(){}`

Fiddle defined

> **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/uh9vw0ao/403/)**

Your **html** file maybe like this

```
<canvas id="my_chart"></canvas>
```

Then your **js** file may look like this

```
fillColor: "#79D1CF",
            strokeColor: "#79D1CF",
            data: [60, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]



 var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart1").getContext("2d");
    var myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(chartData, {
    showTooltips: false,
    onAnimationComplete: function () {
         //Your other ChartJs features defined here



var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.font = //your font
        ctx.fillStyle = //your text color
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";

        this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            dataset.points.forEach(function (points) {
                ctx.fillText(points.value, points.x, points.y - 10);//You can change the x and y position of the text as per your requirement
            });
        })
    }
});
```

//Full attribution goes to the [author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/360067/potatopeelings) and the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631354/how-to-display-data-values-on-chart-js)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that it doesn't work for me, I'm using Version 2.2.0 of Chart.js, but I found the solution in the [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37550150/5962228) you mentioned

Comment: yea,sorry didnt knew about your chart version,issue also resolved here https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/1775

Comment: If my answer satisfied your question then i believe i deserve this bounty thanks,since bounty cannot go to self answered questions  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54998/i-just-awarded-myself-a-bounty/97802#97802