# Getting stacked bars height of segments

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm showing the value of each segment of my vertical stacked bars using the following code

```
options: {
  animation: {
      onComplete: function () {
          var chartInstance = this.chart;
          var ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
          ctx.textAlign = "center";
          ctx.font = "11px Arial";
          ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";

          Chart.helpers.each(this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
              var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
              Chart.helpers.each(meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                  data = dataset.data[index];
                  ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y+4);
              }),this)
          }),this);
      }
  }
}
```

Sometimes segments are only a few pixels in height and the texts of the values overlap. I would like to get the height of each segment in order to hide the value when it won't fit.

Original source (horizontal bars) https://codepen.io/jamiecalder/pen/NrROeB

Comment: The answer provided by jordanwillis here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42556835/show-values-on-top-of-bars-in-chart-js may lead me to the solution...