# Show data values in Chart.js bars (version 3)

Tags: javascript, chart.js, data-visualization

There is a thread with many answers on this topic ([Show values on top of bars in chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42556835/show-values-on-top-of-bars-in-chart-js)), but it's all about version 2.x

- getDatasetMeta() has been deprecated:
  https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.0.2/getting-started/v3-migration.html
- The "datalabels" plugin has not been ported to 3.x:
  https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels

Have you found any working solutions? How can data values be displayed on top of vertical barcharts (or next to horizontal barcharts)?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the beta of the datalabels plugin.

Documentation: https://v2_0_0-rc_1--chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/

Script tag: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0-rc/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>`

Install command: `npm i chartjs-plugin-datalabels@next`

Live example:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.3.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0-rc"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="850" height="520"></canvas>
<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
  
  Chart.register(ChartDataLabels); // first way of registering the plugin, registers them for all your charts
  
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels], // second way of registering plugin, register plugin for only this chart
    data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      datasets: [{
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        label: 'Advisor Closed MTD',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(192,111,94)',
        barThickness: 25,
        datalabels: {
          color: '#FFCE56'
        }

      }],
    },
    options: {
      responsive: false,
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          anchor: 'end', // remove this line to get label in middle of the bar
          align: 'end',
          formatter: (val) => (`${val}%`),
          labels: {
            value: {
              color: 'blue'
            }
          }

        }
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Great... Thank you! 
By any chance... Do you happen to know of a way to add signs (like "%") next to values?

Comment: Yes you can use the formatter option, see updated live sample

Comment: Great, and today is no more a beta, but a real release 2.1.0 :-)