# How do I make the data point tool tips permanently visible in ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I need to make the tooltips for the first and last data points on the chart (line chart) display permanently, whether or not a mouse is hovering. The other data points should not display a tool tip unless hovering over them. How would I accomplish this in ChartJS?

Comment: have you heard about the data-label plugin.. It could help you out. You can modify it. https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631354/how-to-display-data-values-on-chart-js   for reference