# How to Display Data at Edge of Horizontal Bar Chart in Chart JS

Tags: charts, chart.js

I'm Creating One Horizontal Bar Chart Using Chat JS , I Need  Data  to be Displayed at the Edge of Bar ..

[image]

Comment: Possibly similar with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631354/how-to-display-data-values-on-chart-js

Comment: Yes, Thank You Sir , But this same problem how to face Pie Chart ?..

Comment: I Need Horizontal Bar Chart ..