# Chart.js datalabels plugin isn't showing on chart

Tags: chart.js

I have a bar chart from chart.js but I can't get the chart.js datalabels plugin to show the values of each bar within the chart.

Here is the chart.js code...the labels and data within chart.js is pulling from an external google sheet via a simple php array.

The chart.js library is referenced in my header, followed by the chart.js datalabels plugin library:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0"></script>    


<canvas height="225vh" id="yield-comparison-bar-chart"></canvas>


<script type="text/javascript">
    new Chart(document.getElementById("yield-comparison-bar-chart"), {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: [
          '<?php echo $holdings_array[29][3]; ?>', 
          '<?php echo $holdings_array[29][4]; ?>', 
          '<?php echo $holdings_array[29][5]; ?>', 
          '<?php echo $holdings_array[29][6]; ?>', 
          '<?php echo $holdings_array[29][7]; ?>', 
          '<?php echo $holdings_array[29][8]; ?>', 
          '<?php echo $holdings_array[29][9]; ?>',
          ],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Distribution Yield (%)",
              backgroundColor: ["#003b5c", "#b0ced8","#b0ced8","#b0ced8","#b0ced8","#b0ced8","#b0ced8"],
              data: [
                   <?php echo number_format(floatval($holdings_array[30][3]),2); ?>,
                   <?php echo number_format(floatval($holdings_array[30][4]),2); ?>,
                   <?php echo number_format(floatval($holdings_array[30][5]),2); ?>,
                   <?php echo number_format(floatval($holdings_array[30][6]),2); ?>,
                   <?php echo number_format(floatval($holdings_array[30][7]),2); ?>,
                   <?php echo number_format(floatval($holdings_array[30][8]),2); ?>,
                   <?php echo number_format(floatval($holdings_array[30][9]),2); ?>,]
            }
          ]
        },
        options: {
          legend: { display: false },
          title: {
            display: false,
            text: ''
          },
          plugins: {
          datalabels: {
             display: true,
             color: '#333',
             align: 'center',
             anchor: 'center'
          }
       },
          scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        // Include a % sign in the ticks
                        callback: function(value, index, values) {
                            return value + '%';
                           
                        },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false,
                        drawBorder: false,
    
                    },    
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false,
                        drawBorder: false,
    
                    },    
                }]
            } 
        }
    });
    </script>
```

[image: Here is how the chart currently looks]

I would like for the values of each bar to be shown on top them please

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631354/how-to-display-data-values-on-chart-js).

Comment: @sbgib thanks, I had already looked there but none of those solutions worked. It seems the values should show automatically after referencing the the plugins, but they arent

Comment: Is the problem that the values are pulling in from an external source?