# show label inside the chart - angular.js and chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I'm trying to show the chart's information without the necessity of the user having to hover the mouse over in any piece of the chart. I'm using *Chart.js* with *Angular.js*

My doubt is the same of this [question here!](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107380/valores-fixados-em-cima-do-gr%C3%A1fico-angularjs)

*html* code:

```
<div class="wrapper-chart" >
        <canvas
            id="pie"
            class="chart chart-pie"
            chart-data="data"
            chart-labels="labels"
            chart-options="options"
            chart-colors="colors"
            legend = "true"
            chart-series="series">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

*angular* code:

```
angular
    .module('myBeeApp.controllers')
    .controller('chartHome', chartHome);

chartHome.$inject = [
    '$scope'
];
function chartHome(
    $scope
){
        $scope.labels = ["Primavera", "VerÃ£o", "Outono", "Inverno"];
        $scope.data = [32, 53, 14, 79];
        $scope.options = {
            showToolTips: true,
            tooltipEvents: [],
            onAnimationComplete: function() {
                this.showTootip(this.datasets[0].bars,true);
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Quantidade por EstaÃ§Ã£o',
                fontColor: '#ff8c1b',
                fontFamily: 'HelveticaNeue',
                fontSize: 26,
            },
            legend: {
                display: true
            },
            cutoutPercentage: 50,
        };
        $scope.colors = ["#FF7400", "#C85B00", "#FFB77B", "#E3831E"];
}
```

The chart is generated correctly, however there is no info already displayed.

The generated chart(my chart):

[image]

**How I'd like that it would be(with labels):**

[image]

I've already tried this piece of code but **didn't** work for me!

```
$scope.options = {
    tooltipEvents: [],
    showTooltips: true,
    tooltipCaretSize: 0,
    onAnimationComplete: function () {
        this.showTooltip(this.segments, true);
    },
};
```

I've also tried [following these steps!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719156/angular-charts-pie-chart-show-labels-inside-each-slice-of-data) Didn't work at all!(**that's the why I believe it's not a duplicated question**)

version: angular - v1.6.6 ; angular-chart - v1.1.1 ; chart.js - v2.7.1

Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the same [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31725048/3898339) which you mention. I changed the chart type, labels, colors and data. It shows the label in chart without hover as required

[image: Img]

```js
angular.module('App', ["chart.js"]);


angular.module('App').controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window',

  function($scope, $http, $location, $window) {
    $scope.options = {
      tooltipEvents: [],
      showTooltips: true,
      tooltipCaretSize: 0,
      onAnimationComplete: function() {
        this.showTooltip(this.segments, true);
      },
    };

    var diskDataJson = {
      "data": [32, 53, 14, 79],
      "labels": ["Primavera", "VerÃ£o", "Outono", "Inverno"],
      "colours": ["#FF7400", "#C85B00", "#FFB77B", "#E3831E"]
    };

    $scope.pieDiskData = diskDataJson;
  }
]);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/nnnick/Chart.js/v1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/0.8.0/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/0.8.0/dist/angular-chart.css">


<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <canvas id="pie33" chart-options="options" class="chart chart-doughnut chart-xs ng-isolate-scope" height="120" width="240" chart-data="pieDiskData.data" chart-labels="pieDiskData.labels" chart-colours="pieDiskData.colours" chart-legend="true"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27bL66nx/) demo