# PrimeNg Pie Chart - By default show all tooltip?

Tags: angular, chart.js, primeng

I am creating Pie chart using PrimeNg(latest) based on Charts.js 2.7.x in my Angular 6 App. Everything is working perfectly.
But I have a requirement where, by default I want to show all the tooltip in pie chart. 
I want to achieve:[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719156/angular-charts-pie-chart-show-labels-inside-each-slice-of-data)

I found and tried option like below but it is not working. Only Title and legends are working:

`<p-chart type="pie" [data]="data" [options]="options"></p-chart>`

```
this.options = {
  onAnimationComplete: function() {
    this.showTooltip(this.segments, true);
  },

  tooltipEvents: [],

  showTooltips: true,
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'My Title',
    fontSize: 16
  },
  legend: {
    position: 'bottom'
  }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this in PrimeNg? Added[Plunk](https://embed.plnkr.co/UrdmbESto9W6TiMYSpUj/)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-configuration), you need to pass it `intersect` as `false`. By default it's `true`.

Try updating your config like this:

```
this.options = {
  onAnimationComplete: function() {
    this.showTooltip(this.segments, true);
  },

  tooltipEvents: [],

  tooltips: {
    intersect: false
  },

  showTooltips: true,
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'My Title',
    fontSize: 16
  },
  legend: {
    position: 'bottom'
  }
}
```

Comment: It's solved another issue in my Chart :) But not the one which I mentioned. I tried but not able to see all the tooltips.

Comment: Please create a fiddle and share the link if possible.