# How to make label always visible on DoughnutChart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, label, chart.js

I have already gone through this link
[Chart.js - Doughnut show tooltips always?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661197/chart-js-doughnut-show-tooltips-always)

I have implemented the code in the same way on my machine but the chart is not appearing.

The following is my code:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Doughnut Chart</title>
    <script src="Chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="chart" width="200" height="200"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var data = [
{
    value: 300,
    color:"#F7464A",
    highlight: "#FF5A5E"
},
{
    value: 50,
    color: "#46BFBD",
    highlight: "#5AD3D1"
},
{
    value: 100,
    color: "#FDB45C",
    highlight: "#FFC870"
}
]

    var options = 
{
tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>",

onAnimationComplete: function()
{
    this.showTooltip(this.segments, true); 
},

tooltipEvents: [],

showTooltips: true  
}

var context = $('#chart').get(0).getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(context).Pie(data, options);
```

Please can anybody help me out with this trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could forget about jquery leave the `<head></head` as was in the code you posted and substitute

```
var context = $('#chart').get(0).getContext('2d');
```

with

```
var context = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to include this line in your html file to include jquery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you have included that in the header of your page right? i just did that with your copied code and it showed the chart.

Comment: Yeah did that only
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Doughnut Chart</title>
  <script src="Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: you just have to put all the link that i have put in the comment or you can try to download the file with jquery and include like the one you have from charts.js without the ";" at the end.
besides that, try to include first the jquery and then chart.js

Comment: I just cant believe this! i did as you said but it is still not showing CHART
        <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Chart.min.js"></script> 
This time i have downloaded the file

Comment: can you put your html file in a link/page so i can see it?

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/CjRVShxmjiNcRRMfFJZtBd

my index.html page that is the same folder as chart.js

Answer (score 0):

In the code above seems to miss the ref to `jquery` between `<head></head>` tags

Comment: are you talking about this ?
<script src="Chart.js"></script>