# Chart.js doughnut chart tooltip information

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm currently working with chart.js for the first time. I encountered a problem which I'm not able to fix by myself. The tooltip is shown when I hoover the chart, but I want the tooltip to be shown always and outside of the slices. This is what I achieved at the moment:

[image]

The goal I want to achieve is to show slice information outside the doughnut chart (next to each slice). Shown in the following image:

[image]

Anybody out there who had the same problem and fixed this?

Thanks!

Comment: can you make a working fiddle for this?

Comment: And also you can see it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661197/chart-js-doughnut-show-tooltips-always

Comment: @claudios I saw this, but this does still not show the tooltip next to the slice.